# Can Netty integrate STOMP?

Tags: java, websocket, netty, stomp

I am currently using Netty integrated WebSocket to do a chat room, I would like to ask whether Netty supports STOMP protocol, so that Netty+ WebSocket + STOMP can be done? I can't find any examples online because the combination doesn't fit the actual development, or because they're the wrong combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netty provides a STOMP *codec* so in that sense it "supports" STOMP. However, STOMP is a *messaging* protocol and Netty is not a message broker. Therefore, in that sense Netty doesn't support STOMP. In order to support STOMP as a messaging protocol you'd have to implement much more than what Netty provides. See the [STOMP specification](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html) for more details on that.

Comment: Thank you for taking time out of your busy schedule to answer this question. Therefore, according to what you said, if I use Netty+ WebSocket to achieve similar chatting functions, it is not recommended to use Stomp as a sub-protocol of WebSocket?

Comment: I'm not recommending you do anything in particular. I'm just answering your question about integrating Netty, WebSocket, and STOMP. Whether or not it's wise/recommended to implement a STOMP message broker for your use-case is something you'll have to decide as you weigh all your specific pros and cons.